# How do I get different URL Format with parent/child structures & how do I display different templates?

Tags: url, structure, sections, children, parents

I need to create a **features structure section** for a website that will have parent features and child features.

**Q1:** How do I get different URL Format for parent & child pages?

- I need the parent features here: `website.com/features/parent-feature`
- And the Child features here `website.com/parent-feature/child-feature`

**Q2:** How do I display the Parent & Child in different templates? I want the parent features to look more dominant than the child features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get different URL Format for parent & child pages, you need to go to the CP structure settings and edit the **Entry URI Format**. This is how your URI should look like:

`{% if level == 1 %}features/{slug}{% else %}{parent.slug}/{slug}{% endif %}`

For your templating question, if you want a different template for parents and children, you need an if statement in your template file for that structure. So in your CP structure settings, you will have one template file:  `features/feature_entry.twig` and inside that file you will have:

```
{% if entry.children|length %} 

   <!-- If it has a child, it's a parent page -->
   {% include 'features/_parent.twig' %}

{% else %}<!-- it's a child page -->

   {% include 'features/_child.twig' %}

{% endif %}
```

Just like that... You now have 2 different templates in 2 different .twig files.